# Orleans.GrainClient.GetStreamProviders() doesn't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orleans

after calling Orleans.GrainClient.GetStreamProviders() and Orleans.GrainClientGetStream()  I'm getting System.NullReferenceException. I try to add StreamPorvider in the file config and by the code as well. Other methods like GetGrain() works great.

my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- 
    This is a sample client configuration file. 
    For a detailed reference, see "Orleans Configuration Reference.html".
-->
<ClientConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
  <GatewayProvider ProviderType="Config"/>
  <Gateway Address="localhost" Port="30000"/>
  <Statistics MetricsTableWriteInterval="30s" PerfCounterWriteInterval="30s" LogWriteInterval="300s" WriteLogStatisticsToTable="true"/>
  <StreamProviders>
    <Provider Type="Orleans.Providers.Streams.SimpleMessageStream.SimpleMessageStreamProvider" Name="PubSubType" FireAndForgetDelivery="false"/>
    <!--<Provider Type="Orleans.Providers.Streams.Persistent.AzureQueueStreamProvider" Name="AzureQueueProvider" DataConnectionString=""/> -->
  </StreamProviders>
</ClientConfiguration>
```

and error stack trace

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

```
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9964625
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Comment: what version is this on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have same Streams configuration in your silo config, not only client.
Check that names and all parameters are matching (copy\paste the section ;) )